# How to find a function of the recursive algorithm?

Tags: arrays, function, recursion, analysis

My task is to "Examine the code below and derive a function, g(n), that corresponds to the exact total number
of ints that are printed after calling the method moreMystery."

My question is how to find a function that is dependent on the length of array? I would like to see answer, but more significant for me is the explanation of the answer in step by step solution.

```
public void moreMystery ( int [] data ) {
int n = data.length;                  // find the length of the array
moreMysteryContinued (data, n - 1);
}


private void moreMysteryContinued ( int [] data , int i ) {
  if ( i >= 0 ) {
    System.out.print(data[i]);
    moreMysteryContinued(data, i - 1);
    moreMysteryContinued(data, i - 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you come up with? What have you tried?

Comment: I understand how recursion works, but it was the first time when i meet that kind of recursion. I have tried to analyse how does recursion works in that particular case and as i see it will execute every first moreMysteryContinued(data, i - 1) recursion method until meet base case (i == -1) and then will start to execute second recursion starting from the smallest number i.

Comment: i also counted amount of prints that will be executed for certain n number. For instance: 0 -> 0;  1 -> 1;  2 -> 3;  3->7;  4 -> 15. Yet i do not understand the formula itself

Comment: Do you recognize that function? Can you write it in a shorter form?

Comment: Oh! that was my problem. I was trying to find a short function, but the way i was trying to do it wasn't exactly what i needed. Also i didn't know about Mersenne Numbers. Thanks for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

To start I took the print statement counts and tried to derive a formula from that.

```
2^4 -1 = 16 -1 = 15
2^3 -1 = 8 - 1 = 7
2^2 -1 = 4 - 1 = 3
```

So the formula for the amount of prints should be 2^n-1.

I’ll attempt to explain how to find the formula through the code.

For each call to moreMysteryContinued it will produce 2 more print statements. So for n calls to moreMysteryContinued there will be 2^n print statements. I’m not entirely sure where the -1 comes in but based on counting it out the 2^n-1 is the formula for integers printed

Comment: Thanks for solution and explanation! Will try to trace it and understand where does -1 comes from. But in general the formula is exactly what i was trying to find.